# Admin Notifications in backend should not appear again after it been removed or marked as read in version 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, core, adminnotification, ce-1.7.0.0

I am using following Magento version
`Magento 1.7.0.2`

I am getting an issue in Admin Notification. Every time the client logins in admin, Admin Notifications in back end appear again after it been removed or marked as read.

After research, I have found that this issue has already been fixed in version `1.7.0.0`.I have seen this fixes on this URL that is :

https://github.com/SergeyCherepanov/Magento/commit/99c51a74bc29509eccc556a5160786bfc2f27e72#diff-f0bf4d87e8cc9681620b8a4632ebe403L61

As, I am using updated version than it should already be fixed but it’s not. So, please let me know what possible solution should be there to resolve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if ok but you can just disable them all (never found them usefull for clients) Under: System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced > Disable Modules Output simply set Mage_AdminNotification to “Disable”.

Comment: don't want to disable fully. show notification but only for those which are not "marked as read".

Answer (score 3):

Do not need to edit any core file.Follow simple below steps and 100% work for you.

System > Configuration > ADVANCED > Advanced > Mage_AdminNotification > Disable Modules

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by **disabling the adminnotification module**.

You can either do it from

System > Configuration > ADVANCED > Advanced > Disable Modules

**OR**

In your app/etc/modules/Yournamespace_Module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Yournamespace_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Core />
                <Mage_Cms />
            </depends>
        </Yournamespace_Module>
        <Mage_AdminNotification>
                <active>false</active>
        </Mage_AdminNotification>
    </modules>
</config>
```

now run and login to admin panel, you will no longer get the notification.

Comment: don't want to disable fully. show notification but only for those which are not "marked as read".

Comment: Notifications marked as read won't be displayed in magento CE 1.7.0.2. Have you made any changes to code (related to notifications)?

Comment: Does the status of the notice change after you mark it as read?

Comment: no I havn't made any changes in any file related this

Comment: status all the time is: "Reminder: Change Magento`s default phone numbers and callouts before site launch"

Comment: that's the notification you get right?
what are the actions available under `System -> Notifications` for this Notice?
or can you add the screen shot of System -> Notifications page?

Comment: Disabling a notification module is not a solution for me. What if magento throws notifications like to update/reload specific cache later or say some critical notifications.